# How browser zoom affect the iframe's position? when browser zoom, the iframe's origin moves

Tags: iframe, browser, zooming

I have a iframe embedded, and when browser zoom in, i don't know what is the base center for zoom. i thought it should be the top right, but it doesn't.

see this website, http://www.deitte.com/IFrameDemo3/IFrameDemo.html
and ctrl scroll, the layout will mess up.

Answer (score 0):

When you zoom in, you're not just zooming in on the iframe, but the entire page. This also affects the top and left offset positions of all the elements on the page, hence why it changes position.

The `embed` element has it's `width` and `height` set to `100%` though, which adjusts to zoomed view port, hence why the flash element doesn't adjust it's size.

I think part of the problem here is there is a mixed approach to the UI design; most of it is Flash, with the HTML iframe positioned on top of it, in the perfect position such that it looks like they are seamless (at default zoom). It's difficult to get these two to scale in conjunction with each other in this case; there's nothing to bound the size and position of the iframe that is controlled by the flash element.

I am no flash expert, but I would hazard a guess that the flash application currently is not aware of the browser zoom level and is therefore not scaling correctly either; while it's width and height change according to it's container's size, it's font sizes never increase or decrease (amoung other things).

Comment: Hi Vee, thank you for your reply.  I'm aware that the flex app won't respond to the browser zoom , and I can figure out a way to reverse the browser's zoom, so that the no matter how the browser zooms, the embedded frame still at its original size. the problem is that i cannot not figure out the correct (x,y) to reverse the position shifting brought by the zooming....